# How to make the if conditions look cleaner?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to make this if conditions look cleaner and easily to add more Query search in the future as in Open–closed principle?

For example:

```
if (event.queryParameters["name"]) {
    result = await getResultByName(event.queryParameters["name"]);
} else if (event.queryParameters["emailAddress"]) {
    result = await getResultByEmail(event.queryParameters["emailAddress"]);
} else if (event.queryParameters["param1"]) {
    result = await getResultByParam1(event.queryParameters["param1"]);
} else if (event.queryParameters["something1"] && event.queryParameters["something2"]) {
    result = await getResultBySomething(event.queryParameters["something1"], event.queryParameters["something2"]);
}
```

As you can see it look really messy.

Comment: What are you querying? A database?

Comment: And just to be sure the question is clear, what exactly makes this code "less clean"?

Comment: I've voted to close this due to requiring a primarily opinion-based answer. That isn't to say that this isn't a good question--it is a good question. But it's obvious that this topic is sparking way more debate than necessary and it's difficult to formulate an objective answer when the majority of so-called "issues" being discussed are completely hypothetical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a table of entries and use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const lut = [
  { keys: ['name'], getResultBy: getResultByName },
  { keys: ['emailAddress'], getResultBy: getResultByEmail },
  { keys: ['param1'], getResultBy: getResultByParam1 },
  { keys: ['something1', 'something2'], getResultBy: getResultBySomething }
]

const params = event.queryParameters
const entry = lut.find(
  ({ keys }) => keys.every(key => key in params)
)

if (entry) {
  const { keys, getResultBy } = entry
  const result = await getResultBy(...keys.map(key => params[key]))
  ...
}
```

The problem with the original code is that it isn't DRY, and so any incremental modification will inevitably repeat what was already written.

Compare the following two incremental changes:

```
...
{ keys: ['fizz', 'buzz', 'fizzbuzz'], getResultBy: getResultByFizzBuzz }
```

```
...
else if (params.fizz && params.buzz && params.fizzbuzz) {
  result = await getResultByFizzBuzz(params.fizz, params.buzz, params.fizzbuzz);
}
```

And tell me which one you'd rather be typing every time you go back and add a new function.

Comment: This won't work if any of the functions ever need to take additional parameters that aren't in `event.queryParameters` or use other properties of `event`, which is an extremely common requirement. This is overly-complicated and doesn't address the OP's need for easily adding new use-cases in a maintainable way. (Note: Mods deleted the previous comments. If you're going to allow comments on the other answers, you should allow them *on all the answers*.) See the older comments here on why this won't work: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45857645#45857645

Answer (score 2):

Since values are different and functions are different, there's not much place for improvement.

There's no necessity for bracket notation and there's no reason to reference `event` object every time.

It could be written as:

```
const { queryParameters } = event;

if (queryParameters.name) {
    result = await getResultByName(queryParameters.name);
} else if ...
```

No other improvements can be made, unless the same case occurs in several places and could be DRYed up:

```
const paramHandlers = [
  { handler: getResultByName, paramNames: ['name'] },
  ...
];
```

Then `paramHandlers` can be iterated to check if `paramNames` match `event.queryParameters` properties.

Comment: How about new `get()` function for the event query Parameters? eg: `get('email')`

Comment: I don't see a reason to do that. It isn't simpler than `queryParameters.name`. If `queryParameters` takes too much characters, a variable could have a shorter name.

Comment: Also, what about avoiding `else if` and just use multiple `if`?

Comment: This will result in different logic. If there are multiple params, multiple functions will be called. If this is what you want, stick to `if`. Otherwise `else if` is the right way.

Answer (score -3):

So what you have looks perfectly readable, simple, and clean. You could create an event handler list if you need more flexibility:

```
eventHandlers = [nameHandler, emailHandler, ...];
var result;
for (var handler of eventHandlers) {
    if (result = handler(event)) break;
}
```

In this example, the event handlers are functions that return a result if the event was consumed and processing should end. In your case your result can be a Promise or any arbitrary value.

Comment: `for...in` is wrong. I think you meant `for...of`. You're also not using a consistent variable name, i.e. `eventHandlers` and `handlers`.

Comment: No, this answer is correct. The goal isn't to write the OP's code for him, but to give him the right approach to use.

Comment: How would you consume the `result` using this approach?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger The handlers can return a result as above.

Comment: Your `handler` methods cannot be asynchronous, or the first one would always return early since all promises are truthy regardless of whether they're resolved or rejected. There is also no common convention of conditionally returning a falsy value or a promise from the same function--that's just confusing, and difficult to implement with proper error handling. Not to mention it would have to be re-implemented in every handler.

Comment: This solution fails to simplify the example code and underhandedly conceals the boilerplate that was conveniently omitted in each of the `handler` functions that would be required to wrap the functions used in the OP.

Comment: Wrong @PatrickRoberts. There is absolutely nothing here that prevents async processing. You should learn how Promises work. Obviously a handler would only return a Promise if it accepted the event. There's no boilerplate at all either. The handlers, by definition, each handle a *different use case*. Your other comments aren't relevant.

Comment: Your code could be simplified as `const result = eventHandlers.reduce((handler, result) => result || handler(event), undefined);`, if that's what you're suggesting.

Comment: That's not a simplification - it's a pointless obfuscation and is less efficient that the simpler version I posted.

Comment: I'd argue that `if (result = handler(event))` is what's obfuscated. One might mistake that for a typo if they were just skimming.

Comment: Showing what `nameHandler` looks like and how `result` is treated would be an improvement to the answer. I understand how it works but users that could benefit from the answer may not.

Comment: @estus There's no need to gold-plate something that's already simple enough to understand. Feel free to use the edit link if you have something to add.